# How do I pass variable from PHP to Javascript using Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using the Zend Framework 2 and would like to pass a variable from my action to javascript.

**Controller Code:**

```
fooAction
{
return 'bar'
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$.post('foo', { week: week, day: day, time: time }, function(data) { $(id).html(data); });
```

I would like to pass the value 'bar' back to javascript.  Currently if I do something like the below I get the correct results.  I would like to use a variable from the action instead of hard keying it.

```
$.post('foo', { week: week, day: day, time: time }, function(data) { $(id).html('bar'); });
```

Many Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `How do I pass variable from PHP to Javascript` Woo can't even count anymore how many times this was asked before!

Comment: You don't pass it, you print it. `echo` it in the PHP being called by the ajax and it shows up in the `data` variable.